# Unable to connect to ASP.NET web api when I add additional parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-web-api-routing

I am trying understand Web Api 2 (MVC project in Visual Studio).

The method is

```
  [HttpPost]
  public string Post(int id, string e, bool o)
  ///code removed
```

Using Postman, I can query using `Post` and the path `http://localhost:62093/api/Demo/5`. This works and returns the expected value.

Now I want to add more parameters and this is where it goes wrong!

I have updated my method to

```
    [HttpPost]
    public string Post(int id, string e, bool o)
```

Now when I attempt to query this using (again) `Post` and the path `http://localhost:62093/api/Demo/5` I see

> "Message": "The requested resource does not support http method 'POST'."

I then try to change the URL, so when I use `Post` and the new path `http://localhost:62093/api/Demo/5/a/false` I see an HTML file response of

> The resource cannot be found

This has been mentioned before on Stackoverflow and from what I've understood is about the URL being 'incorrect'

Thinking this could be an issue with routes I updated mine to

```
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}/{s}/{o}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional, s = RouteParameter.Optional, o = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
```

But the same issue persists. I'm not sure what I've done wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a routing issue. you have not configured your routes correctly.

First let us update the *`WebApiConfig.cs`* file

```
public static class WebApiConfig {
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config) {
        // Attribute routing.
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        // Convention-based routing.
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

Now with that configured I would suggest using ***Attribute routing***

```
public class DemoController : ApiController {
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("api/Demo/{id:int}/{e}/{o:bool}")] //Matches POST api/Demo/5/a/false
    public IHttpActionResult Post(int id, string e, bool o) {
        return Ok();
    }
}
```

I would finally suggest reading up on [Attribute Routing in ASP.NET Web API 2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2) to get a better understanding on how to properly route to your API controllers

Comment: Thank you especially for the link to Attribute Routing.